# How do you make the content of a div move with a blind effect rather then being revealed by it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now my blind effect reveals (or uncovers) the already-in-place contents of a div. I want the content to slide in with the blind rather then already being there.

Whats the best way to do this?

ex. i want to be able to see something positioned at the bottom of the div the whole time not just after the effect is done.

Thanks!

Comment: As in like, using `hide()` to hide the element first, and then calling `slideDown()`?

Comment: Possibly? Right now i doing a prependTo with the blind effect.

Comment: `.prependTo("#items").show("blind", 500)`

Comment: Hrrm, this seems to result in a slightly different effect with the same problem. The inner content is mostly in place and is being revealed by the bottom border instead of have everything move down together. ex. i want to be able to see something positioned at the bottom of the div the whole time not just after the effect is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create it on the fly and then slide it in:

```
$('<div/>').css('display','none').appendTo('body').html('your content').slideDown();
```

Comment: This results in the same problem, i want to be able to see something positioned at the bottom of the div the whole time not just after the effect is done.

Comment: Ah yes, then you have to animate. Hide the div behind another element and then animate the dimension you're moving from (or towards). To slide right, animate the left property, like this: `$('div').animate({left:'+=100'}, 1000)`.